# how to check if browser window has focus in "mobile web browser"

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I am not able to test this event on chrome mobile web browser,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hasFocus

I would like to test application, such that user clicks on home page of mobile phone and then I want to take certain action in my application.

Note : Basically on web browser I am able to achieve this functionality using document.hasfocus, window.blur but not on mobile web browser

For eg.
http://jsfiddle.net/QkzvP/

```
$(function(){

    window['hasFocus'] = false;

    $(window)
        .bind('focus', function(ev){
            window.hasFocus = true;
            $('#event').append('<div>'+(new Date()).getTime()+' focus</div>');
        })
        .bind('blur', function(ev){
            window.hasFocus = false;
            $('#event').append('<div>'+(new Date()).getTime()+' blur</div>');
        })
        .trigger('focus');

    setInterval(function() {
        $('#event').append('<div>'+(new Date()).getTime()+' has focus '+(window.hasFocus ? 'yes' : 'no')+'</div>');
    }, 1000);
});
```

OR
http://jsfiddle.net/Msjyv/3/

```
function check()
{
    if(document.hasFocus() == lastFocusStatus) return;

    lastFocusStatus = !lastFocusStatus;
    statusEl.innerText = lastFocusStatus ? 'with' : 'without';
}

window.statusEl = document.getElementById('status');
window.lastFocusStatus = document.hasFocus();

check();
setInterval(check, 200);
```

Comment: Above jsfiddle example works well within web browser, but when same example tried in chrome mobile web browser then "blur\document.hasfocus" events do not work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.joshmorony.com/monitoring-online-and-offline-states-in-an-ionic-application/

Comment: I am looking for mobile web browser events specifically, unfortunately no path found yet.

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause